# what does " An SQL server Express 2008 instance is a copy of the sqlserver.exe executable file " mean?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to DBMS and MSSQL server and was studying about installing multiple instances of sql servers in one machine. what I failed to understand is why is an instance of sql server called a copy of sqlservr.exe executable when that is a software created instance where as the other is an OS service for my machine. I am confused big times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you are referring to this article:
[Database Engine Instances (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Windows Services work like this: You can use the same .exe for multiple entries in the "Services" table, as long as the "Service Name" in the list is unique.

So, if you want to run multiple SQL Server instances on the same machine, you will have multiple windows services with different names (in particular related to the instances names you choose during SQL Server installation) but they still rely on the sqlservr.exe file.

I think that the documentation you are reading talks about "copies of sqlservr.exe" just to let you know that there is no shared memory or state between different SQL Server Instance processes. So, everytime a new instance of sqlservr.exe is asked to the OS, it reads the file binary data and maps it to a different memory space.

Here you can find more detailed informations about that .exe:
[sqlservr Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlservr-application?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! makes so much sense now. :) :)

Comment: I'm happy to know i helped :)